# Creating ContextBinding XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having problems setting the DataContext for all fields that are inside a stackPanel. What I would like to do is set the Data Context as vm:ViewModel. But it's not working and when I ask VS for assistance with DataBinding it Displays the TextBox.DataContext inside the TextBox. Is there a way to only set it once or do I have to set it for each control?

```xml
    <StackPanel DataContext="vm:ViewModel">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="206,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <TextBox.DataContext>
                <vm:ViewModel/>
            </TextBox.DataContext>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your DataContext to refer to an instance of your ViewModel.

`DataContext="vm:ViewModel"` is not creating an instance of the ViewModel...it's just setting a string.

Use Property Element syntax instead:

```
    <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModel/>
    </StackPanel.DataContext>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="206,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

And if you do that, then there's no need/in fact it's probably wrong to create another one in your TextBox.DataContext...you just want to inherit the DataContext of the StackPanel.

I'll just show you another way to create a ViewModel and to refer to the instance of it so you have a bigger picture.....that is to create it in resources, and then refer to that resource in the binding...here's an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModel x:Key="myviewmodel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackp" DataContext="vm:ViewModel">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myviewmodel}, Path=FirstNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="206,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Another example that sets the DataContext at a higher level in the tree:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="206,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Colinsmith, So if I wanted it available to the whole .xaml file I would define the dataContext at the top most level? And everytime I setup a dataContext like that I am creating an instance?

Comment: Yes you can define it at the topmost DAtaContext and it will be inherited by all lower level elements.

Comment: Is it better to use resources? Or just when more than one viewModel is needed?

Comment: Resources is just a different way...it's more explicit...sometimes you want that, sometimes you don't....it depends on what you want to do. Yes multiple ViewModels could be handled by putting them as different keyed Resources....or you could handle that case by having a ViewModel that composed 2 or more ViewModels....lots of different options.