# How to bind the view model to the view

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I am having trouble binding my `View Model` to my `View`. I am a beginner with `MVVM`, but I believe I am implementing my system (almost) correctly. I have a `Model` that contains data, which I am getting in my `View Model`, and then when my page is navigated to, I am attempting to grab that `View Model` data and binding it to the `View`.

My issue is that I have a `ListBox` in my `View` with 3 objects per item, and I cannot seem to bind to it correctly for each item in my list.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ListBox x:Name="FavoritesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding FavoriteItems}" 
         SelectionChanged="FavoritesListBox_SelectionChanged">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image x:Name="favicon" Source="{Binding Favicon}" 
               Width="50" Height="50"/>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="favoritesName" Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="favoritesAddress" 
                       Text="{Binding Address}" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>                
</ListBox>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public FavoritesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        FavoritesListBox.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
    }
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;        

    public static MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
            if (viewModel == null)
                viewModel = new MainViewModel();

            return viewModel;
        }
    }
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> FavoriteItems { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //FavoriteItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        FavoriteItems = Settings.FavoritesList.Value;
    }
```

**Settings.cs (The Model)**

```
public static Setting<ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>> FavoritesList = 
    new Setting<ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>>(
        "Favorites", 
        new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>());
```

**ItemViewModel.cs**

```
private string _favicon;
    public string Favicon
    {
        get
        {
            return _favicon;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _favicon)
            {
                _favicon = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Favicon");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _address;
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return _address;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _address)
            {
                _address = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Address");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

..and this is where and how I am saving each item (which should have three properties listed in the `ItemViewModel`

```
void addToFavorites_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var favoriteItem = 
        new ItemViewModel{
            Favicon = "", 
            Name = "", 
            Address = TheBrowser.currentUrl() };
        Settings.FavoritesList.Value.Add(favoriteItem);            
}
```

Where `FavoritesList` is populated using an `ItemViewModel` containing 3 objects. The list is being populated correctly because during debugging I can see the entities in `FavoritesList`, but I am having an issue calling these entities in the `view model` to show up in my `ListBox` in the `view`?

I believe I am binding incorrectly but I'm not sure how to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151618/creating-contextbinding-xaml that may help you. I've been working on the same thing as well.

Comment: If you know we are going to use a viewmodel for your view to bind some of the properties, why we are using that "delay creation" of viewmodel ?

Comment: I don't see your `ListBox.ItemTemplate` in your XAML. Your `ListBox` gets populated with a collection of `ItemViewModel`, however you need to set the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to a `DataTemplate` containing your controls that bind to `ItemViewModel` to tell WPF how to draw each `ItemViewModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML you bind to paths `Name` and `Address` do you have these 2 properties defined in your `ItemViewModel`?

**Update after reading your code properly:**

You are not updating the datatemplate of the Items of the Listbox. This is what you need to do:

```
<ListBox x:Name="FavoritesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding FavoriteItems}" SelectionChanged="FavoritesListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <Image x:Name="favicon" Source="{Binding Favicon}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="favoritesName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="favoritesAddress" Text="{Binding Address}" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Yes, everything is in the `ItemViewModel`. It seems that the Items of FavoritesItems observablecollection in my viewmodel are the Project1.ViewModels.ItemViewModel every time, but within each one of those are the properties I need to expose which are correctly populated.

Comment: Ok I believe I narrowed my problem down to how I save the data in the first place. 
`void addToFavorites_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var favoriteItem = new ItemViewModel { Favicon = "", Name = "", Address = TheBrowser.currentUrl() };
            Settings.FavoritesList.Value.Add(favoriteItem);            
        }` .

Comment: So, if it understand you correctly, when you debug, you can see that the DataContext on the ListBoxItem are instances of ItemViewModels. Is that so? If that is the case the i would suggest that you post the code for the ItemViewModel so that one can check where the issue is. Please update your question with ItemViewModel code.

Comment: Yes, on the additional code on the bottom of the question, when I attempt to save to my `Settings.Favorites.Values` list, the actual item saved is an instance of the ItemViewModel, which includes the three items i need to bind my listbox to in another view.

Comment: The problem is in your XAML actually :) I updated my solution accordingly. Please mark as answer if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting your DataContext to your viewmodel, (as mentioned in the comment linking to [Creating ContextBinding XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151618/creating-contextbinding-xaml)) , you also need to have your view model implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) (including `ItemViewModel`, which you don't show in your question)

Comment: I have tried all that, but maybe this detail will help. I notice that in my Listbox all i'm seeing is the text "Project1.ViewModels.ItemViewModels" (Project1 being the name of my project